# GPUImage: Overreleasing frame buffer after memory warning

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

I develop an application that uses GPUImage framework. And I have some issues with it. Application captures video from camera, adds some additional information on the each frame, and stores it in files. Video writing can be interrupted by user or by system, and can be restarted again. After several begin/stop recording iterations application receives memory warning and application crashes in the assertion:

```
NSAssert(framebufferReferenceCount > 0, @"Tried to overrelease a framebuffer, did you forget to call -useNextFrameForImageCapture before using -imageFromCurrentFramebuffer?");
```

Here is how I configure GPUImage:

[image]

First, I open camera and configure preview:

```
-(void)openCamera:(NSString *)preset
{
    self.camera = [[GPUImageVideoCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:preset
                                                      cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
    self.camera.outputImageOrientation = self.orientation;
    [self.camera addTarget:self.preview];

    [self.camera startCameraCapture];
}
```

Second, when user presses button, I initiate recording

```
-(void)addMovieWriter
{
    self.writingChain = [GPUImageFilter new];

    self.blendFilter = [GPUImageNormalBlendFilter new];
    [self.writingChain addTarget:self.blendFilter];

    self.uiElement = [[GPUImageUIElement alloc] initWithView:_internalView];
    [self.uiElement addTarget:self.blendFilter];

    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [self.writingChain setFrameProcessingCompletionBlock:^(GPUImageOutput *output, CMTime time) {
        [weakSelf.uiElement update];
    }];

    self.writer = [[GPUImageMovieWriter alloc] initWithMovieURL:self.movieURL size:[self writerSize]];
    [self.blendFilter addTarget:self.writer];

    [self.camera addTarget:self.writingChain];
    [self.writer startRecording];
}
```

Third, this way I interrupt writing:

```
-(void)removeMovieWriter
{
    [self.camera removeTarget:self.writingChain];
    [self.writingChain removeAllTargets];

    [self.writer finishRecording];

    self.writer = nil;
    self.uiElement = nil;
    self.writingChain = nil;
}
```

How can I avoid this issue. Maybe I mistaken somewhere. Thank for any help.